# I used Google Takeout, how do I remove this data?

Tags: google-account, google

Google Chrome Bookmarks, extensions and history. I don't use chrome anymore.

Google Play library, I cleared it in google play but the installs.json and library.json are still huge and contain uninstalled apps.

And lastly all Google Play reviews I did.

(This is not off-topic, since it is about google play and chrome)

Comment: That's rather not an Android related question. If you're European, you could refer to the GDPR and demand deletion from Google.

Comment: I do not want to remove my account, just that data. The Right to be forgotten removes everything

Comment: I didn't say demand account deletion. And I'm not talking about the "right to be (completely) forgotten". I'm talking [GDPR's right to erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation#Right_to_erasure) which replaced that. Quoting from the Wikipedia article: "Article 17 provides that the data subject has the right to request erasure of personal data related to them on any one of a number of grounds". For details, see e.g. [here](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing much we can do except giving you a pointer: if you're an European citizen, [GDPR article 17](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/) gives you the right to demand erasure of your personal data. Quoting from paragraph 1:

> The data subject shall have the right to obtain from the controller the erasure of personal data concerning him or her without undue delay and the controller shall have the obligation to erase personal data without undue delay …

After that, a list of conditions follows. For your case, the very first one (a) should apply:

> the personal data are no longer necessary in relation to the purposes for which they were collected or otherwise processed;

Some of the others might as well.

**Summing up:** if you want those data erased, you should reach out to Google demanding erasure according to Article 17 GDPR. To my knowledge, "without undue delay" is interpreted "ASAP" with a cap of maximum 30 days.